# Map array inside object inside array into a single array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects, where each object has a property whose value is another array, like this

```
[
  {
    location: 'somewhere',
    location_id: 1,
    parts: [
      {
        part_id: 1,
        description: 'foo',
        qty: 1,
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I need to map these arrays into a single array like this

```
[
  {
    part_id: 1,
    description: 'foo',
    qty: 1
  },
  {
    part_id: 2,
    description: 'bar',
    qty: 1
  }
]
```

I tried using reduce like 
`newArr: arr.reduce((a,b) => a.parts.concat(b.parts))` but get the error 'Cannot read property concat of undefined.' I also tried providing the initialValue argument of reduce as an empty array but same error.

As a bonus, I will eventually need the final array to not contain duplicates of parts: I.e. if a part is in two locations, it would just combine the quantity.

Open to solutions using es6 but needs to not modify original array

Comment: You will need to specify an initial value. The first parameter to `reduce` callback is the accumulator array, so it won't have a `parts` property.

Comment: `[].concat(...arr.map(item => item.parts))` Doesn't create that many intermediate Arrays as the approach with `reduce`

Comment: How does the result include this: `part_id: 2,  description: 'bar'` when there's nothing in the input that resembles it?

Comment: I just gave one object in the array as an example to show the structure, I didn't think it would be necessary to list out multiple objects.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge/flatten an array of arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865025/merge-flatten-an-array-of-arrays-in-javascript)

Comment: He/she was asking how to flatten array of arrays. I am asking how to immutably map array inside object inside array of objects into single array, and also how to do so while avoiding duplicates inside said array (though nobody has answered with this yet) .

Comment: @wizloc for that you need to explain how you define a duplicate, and how exactly two/multiple "identical" objects should be reduced to a single result. *"if a part is in two locations, it would just combine the quantity"* doesn't explain much for someone who's not familiar with your project and data. Like your snippet doesn't even contain any "quantities"

Comment: @Thomas yes I obviously forgot a crucial piece of information. I edited the question

Comment: @wizloc ok, and what about the questions I've asked? What are duplicates? And how to combine them? there are multiple things what you could mean with these terms (duplicate and combine). Like if they have the same part_id but different descriptions, are they duplicates? what about the other way around? are there other properties that would define two objects as duplicates? how to combine two objects with the same part_id but different descriptions? ... Your request is anything but clear

Comment: Having `{ part_id: 1, description: 'foo' }` and `{ part_id: 1, description: 'bar' }` would make the part_id redundant and I think most people would assume a duplicate is when you have `[ { part_id: 1, description: 'foo', qty: 1 }, { part_id: 1, description: 'foo', qty: 3 } ]`, which when resolved would combine the quantities and give `{ part_id: 1, description: 'foo', qty: 4 }`. If there were any stipulations other than the quantity I would have written so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution uses [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to combine all objects in sub-arrays into a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), with `part_d` as key, and the `qty` the result of the combined quantities. When a new `part_id` is found, a new object is created by [spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals) the part into a new object, and overriding `qty` with 0.

The Map is then converted back to an array by [spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) the [`Map.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values) iterator:

```js
const data = [{"location":"somewhere","location_id":1,"parts":[{"part_id":1,"description":"foo","qty":1}]},{"location":"somewhere2","location_id":2,"parts":[{"part_id":1,"description":"foo","qty":3},{"part_id":2,"description":"bar","qty":1}]}];

const result = [...
  data.reduce((r, { parts }) => {
    (parts || []).forEach((o) => {
      r.has(o.part_id) || r.set(o.part_id, { ...o, qty: 0 });

      r.get(o.part_id).qty += o.qty;
    });

    return r;
  }, new Map())
.values()];

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure you want to map the *arrays* and not the objects inside:

```js
const input = [
  {
    location: 'somewhere',
    location_id: 1,
    parts: [
      {
        part_id: 1,
        description: 'something'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    location: 'somewhere2',
    location_id: 22,
    parts: [
      {
        part_id: 2,
        description: 'something'
      }
    ]
  }
];

const mapped = input.map(outerObj => outerObj.parts[0]);
console.log(mapped);
```

Comment: Sorry i do need to map the objects inside. I edited the question to show the format of the expected output

Comment: Simple, just change `=> outerObj.parts` to `=> outerObj.parts[0]` to select the first element in an array

Answer (score 1):

This adds all part objects into the base and removes the parts array. It will modify the old object.

```js
let arr = [
  {
    location: 'somewhere',
    location_id: 1,
    parts: [
      {
        part_id: 1,
        description: 'something'
      }
    ]
  }
]

arr.map(m => {
  m.parts.forEach(p => Object.assign(m, p))
  delete m.parts;
})

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: I guess from the edit this is not it. I'll leave it up anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array#reduce` to first join all your `parts` array of each object. Then use `array#reduce` to group each object in the result array on `part_id` and `description` and sum up the `qty` for each unique object. Then get all the values from this object.

```js
const input = [ { location: 'somewhere', location_id: 1, parts: [ { part_id: 1, description: 'foo', qty: 1 } ] }, { location: 'somewhere2', location_id: 22, parts: [ { part_id: 2, description: 'something', qty: 3 } ] }, { location: 'somewhere2', location_id: 22, parts: [ { part_id: 2, description: 'something', qty: 4 } ] } ],
      result = Object.values(input.reduce((r, {parts}) => r.concat(parts),[])
        .reduce((r,o) => {
          r[`${o.part_id}_${o.description}`] = r[`${o.part_id}_${o.description}`] || {...o, qty: 0};
          r[`${o.part_id}_${o.description}`].qty += o.qty;
          return r;
        },{}));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

**This question may have two scenarios :**

1. each location have single object under parts array.

   **DEMO**

```js
let jsonObj = [
  {
    location: 'somewhere',
    location_id: 1,
    parts: [
      {
        part_id: 1,
        description: 'foo',
        qty: 1,
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    location: 'somewhere',
    location_id: 2,
    parts: [
      {
        part_id: 2,
        description: 'foo',
        qty: 1,
      }
    ]
  }
];

let res = jsonObj.map(obj => obj.parts[0]);
console.log(res);
```

2. Single location have multiple objects under parts array.

   **DEMO**

```js
let jsonObj = [
  {
    location: 'somewhere',
    location_id: 1,
    parts: [
      {
        part_id: 1,
        description: 'foo',
        qty: 1,
      },
      {
        part_id: 2,
        description: 'foo',
        qty: 1,
      }
    ]
  }
];

let res = jsonObj[0].parts;
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation. What worked for me is defining a new array and then `array.push(part)` from inside a double map function:

```
const input = [{
    location: 'somewhere',
    location_id: 1,
    parts: [{
        part_id: 1,
        description: 'something'
      },
      {
        part_id: 2,
        description: 'something'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    location: 'somewhere2',
    location_id: 22,
    parts: [{
        part_id: 3,
        description: 'something'
      },
      {
        part_id: 4,
        description: 'something'
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

if this is your input..

```
var list = []
input.map(item => {
  item.parts.map(part => {
    list.push(part);
  });
});
```